# android clear ediitext in onclicklistener

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have one `edittext`. First time my edittext's `settext` is 1 and I want to clear this text in editttext `click` and input new keyboard values
I wrote code but not working

```
price_counter = (EditText) rootView
            .findViewById(R.id.strada_price_counter);
price_counter.setText("1");

price_counter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        price_counter.setText("");

    }
});
```

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/strada_price_counter"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/strada_buy_btn"
        android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/strada_buy_btn"
        android:background="@drawable/input_value"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:inputType="number">
</EditText>
```

this code not working if anyone knows solution please help me

Comment: Please show the code where you find/create the price_counter variable.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to call `setOnClickListener` on `EditText`. Register click listener for a button and call `settext` for `EditText` on button click.

Comment: no sir.meybe you did not understad me.default settext in my edittext is 1 and when i click my edittext i would to delete this 1 and input new values from keyboard

Answer (score 0):

Update your code to the following:

```
price_counter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((EditText)v).setText("");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code... This might be you are looking for

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener 
{
    EditText et;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        et=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        et.setText("1");
        et.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            et.setText("");
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: you can replace my edit text id and variables with yours... or you can directly run this code....